# registros duplicados de una consulta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy realizando una consulta para buscar todos aquellos productos que no estén relacionados a una tabla llamada `Stock` donde el campo `Ruta` dentro de la tabla `Stock` sea diferente del `id` que estoy pasando por la url, eso quiere decir buscar todos aquellos productos que no estén asociados a `Stock`, donde la ruta de dicho `Stock` sea igual al parametro de la url.

Lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
@productos = Producto.joins('left outer join stock on productos.Clave=stock.Articulo')
                     .select('productos.*,stock.Articulo')
                     .where('stock.ruta != ? AND productos.Status = ?', params[:id], "A")
```

Tengo un pequeño problema y es que estoy buscando aquellos registros que no estén asociados al `Stock` donde el campo `Ruta` sea diferente del `id` que estoy pasando como parametro. 
Cuando el producto no está asociado al `Stock` y creo un `Stock` asociado al producto, este no trae la consulta, y es justo lo que quiero, pero si el producto ya está asociado a otro `Stock`, así lo tenga asociado al `Stock` con la `Ruta` id de parametro, lo sigue trayendo debido a que otro `Stock` con otra `Ruta` id lo tiene.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

la estructura de las tablas son:
un "Producto" tiene muchos "Stock" y un "Stock" pertenece a un "Producto"

Producto: Clave, Producto, Status

Stock: IdStock, Articulo, Ruta

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48973/discussion-on-question-by-luisc-registros-duplicados-de-una-consulta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debemos buscar primero todos los artículos que tienen la ruta que no deseamos, y los **excluimos** del resto de artículos, que son los que vamos a obtener.

```
create temp table mcprod (clave varchar(10), producto text, status char(1));
create temp table mcstock (id int, articulo varchar(10), ruta int);
insert into mcprod values ('0001', 'Producto 1', 'A');
insert into mcprod values ('0002', 'Producto 2', 'A');
insert into mcprod values ('0003', 'Producto 3', 'N');
insert into mcstock values (1, '0001', 1);
insert into mcstock values (2, '0001', 2);
insert into mcstock values (3, '0001', 3);
insert into mcstock values (4, '0002', 1);
insert into mcstock values (5, '0002', 2);
insert into mcstock values (6, '0002', 5);


select mcprod.clave, mcprod.producto 
from mcprod
where mcprod.status = 'A' 
and mcprod.clave not in (select distinct articulo from mcstock where ruta=3); 

| clave |  articulo  |
|-------|------------|
|  0002 | Producto 2 |
|-------|------------|
```

http://rextester.com/EUJG9349